# Is this a bug in the passlib base64 encoding?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, base64, passlib

I am trying to decode an re-encode a bytesytring using `passlib`s base64 encoding:

```
from passlib.utils import binary

engine = binary.Base64Engine(binary.HASH64_CHARS)
s2 = engine.encode_bytes(engine.decode_bytes(b"1111111111111111111111w"))

print(s2)
```

This prints `b'1111111111111111111111A'` which is of course not what I expected. The last character is different.

Where is my mistake? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a bug.

In all variants of Base64, every encoded character represents just 6 bits and depending on the number of bytes encoded you can end up with 0, 2 or 4 insignificant bits on the end.
In this case the encoded string `1111111111111111111111w` is 23 characters long, that means 23*6 = 138 bits which can be decoded to 17 bytes (136 bits) + 2 insignifcant bits.

The encoding you use here is not Base64 but [Hash64](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.utils.binary.html#passlib.utils.binary.HASH64_CHARS)

> Base64 character map used by a number of hash formats; the ordering is wildly different from the standard base64 character map.

In the character map
`HASH64_CHARS = u("./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")`
we find `A` on index 12 (`001100`) and `w` on index 60 (`111100`)

Now the 'trick' here is, that
[`binary.Base64Engine(binary.HASH64_CHARS)`](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.utils.binary.html#passlib.utils.binary.Base64Engine) has a default parameter  `big=False`, which means that the encoding is done in little endian format by default.

In your example it means that `w` is `001111` and `A` is `001100`. During decoding the last two bits are cut off as they are not needed as explained above. When you encode it again, `A` is taken as the first character in the character map that can be used two encode `0011` plus two insignifiant bits.